# Bash input/output in C++

Tags: c++, bash, input

I'm writing program in C++ (for XAMPP communication) and I want to execute command which I have in strings (I know that this is simply system("command")) but I want to get the output from bash to C++ to string. I've founded several threads about this, but no which solved Bash -> C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `FILE *popen(const char *command, const char *mode)` function. Then, you can read the file it returns to get the output of your call.

It's like using a pipe to redirect the output of the command you used to a file in the hard drive and then read the file, but you don't get to create a file in the hard drive.

[The documentation of the popen() is here.](http://www.opengroup.org/pubs/online/7908799/xsh/popen.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the [popen](http://www.opengroup.org/pubs/online/7908799/xsh/popen.html) function, and read the output from the FILE it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Standard Output Redirection to redirect the standard output to a file stream
and then use it to read to a string.

[Dup()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup)

Comment: Indeed, if the C++ program reads stdin then you can issue a cammand like:   bash_command | cppProgram | string